# How do you deal with the "Kidnapped robot problem"

Tags: ros, mapping, 3d-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Having a map, and the robot "waking up" at an unknown position, what methods are currently used to recover the position?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203165/how-do-you-deal-with-the-%22kidnapped-robot-problem%22/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2015-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Usually the two main approaches are kalman filter or particle filter.
I implemented particle filter in the past and it gives very good results.
Hope this helps,

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2015-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0